# Query for given number of events from windows log

Tags: c#, .net, windows, events

I am trying to extract last N events with given level from Windows evens log. After MSDN page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671200.aspx ) I came up with the following solution (which works):

```
List<string> records = new List<string>();
string queryString = string.Format("*[System/Level={0}]", level);
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery(eventLogLocation, PathType.FilePath, queryString);
eventsQuery.ReverseDirection = true;
var reader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
var record = reader.ReadEvent();

while (record != null && numRecords > 0)
{
    records.Add(record.FormatDescription());
    record = reader.ReadEvent();
}
```

Is it possible to query for a given number of events without going though them in a loop?